# An alert placed on an input on jsfiddle.net repeats anywhere from 3 all the way up to 57 times. Why?

Tags: jquery, alert

HTML:

```
<input>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
$('input').focusin(function(){
    alert('input focused')
});
```

[Live copy on jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/nn5PT/)

Very strange behavior: when using jQuery to make a simple alert when an `<input>` or `<textarea>` gains `focus`, it causes the alert to repeat anywhere from 3 times all the way up to repeating 57 times. It's random, and that's without changing any code, sometimes it alerts 14 or 26 or 35 etc.

Does anyone know why this happens? Am I missing something?

Edit: just realized this is happening in Chrome, but firefox 4 isn't repeating the alert.

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time. (I've done it for you on this occasion.)

Comment: that makes perfect sense, i'll do that from now on, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input probably loses it's focus when the alert pops up, and regains it when it's closed, causing it to fire again.

Try using `console.log("input focus");` or any other means to see the event fire without making use of an alert and see if the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The code is hooking the `focusin` event and then doing something to take focus away from the field temporarily (by taking it away from the window). When you dismiss the alert, the focus transfers back to the window and the field... Rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

It does work normally for me, it alerts just once ...

try

`console.log('input fired');`

instead of  alert